# How to input number on JTextField using buttons from another class

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to input numbers to pin_textField from ATMScreenPanel using the buttons from ATMKeypadPanel class but I don't know how. I tried using objects although I learned that it doesn't actually change the value from the actual class when I used it. Can someone please teach me how to do it?

code for ATMScreenPanel

```
public class ATMScreenPanel extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList<String> pins = new ArrayList<>();
    JLabel label;
    static JTextField pin_textField;

    ATMScreenPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setLayout(null);
        pin_textField = new JTextField("");
        pin_textField.setHorizontalAlignment(pin_textField.CENTER);
        pin_textField.setBounds(98, 110, 300, 50);
        add(pin_textField);

        label = new JLabel("Enter your pin number");
        label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        label.setBounds(90, 50, 400, 50);
        add(label);

        ATMKeypadPanel keys = new ATMKeypadPanel();

    }
}
```

code for ATMKeypadPanel

```
public class ATMKeypadPanel extends JPanel{

    JButton[] buttons;

    ATMKeypadPanel(){
        buttons = new JButton[14];
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1,2,1,2);

        handler buttonHandler = new handler();
        buttons[0] = new JButton("1");
        buttons[0].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,60));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        buttons[0].addActionListener( buttonHandler);
        add(buttons[0],gbc);

        buttons[1] = new JButton("2");
        buttons[1].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,60));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        buttons[1].addActionListener( buttonHandler);
        add(buttons[1],gbc);

        buttons[2] = new JButton("3");
        buttons[2].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,60));
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        buttons[2].addActionListener( buttonHandler);

        add(buttons[2],gbc);

        buttons[3] = new JButton("4");
        buttons[3].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,60));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        buttons[3].addActionListener( buttonHandler);

        add(buttons[3],gbc);

        buttons[4] = new JButton("5");
        buttons[4].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,60));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        buttons[4].addActionListener( buttonHandler);

        add(buttons[4],gbc);

        buttons[5] = new JButton("6");
        buttons[5].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,60));
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        buttons[5].addActionListener( buttonHandler);

        add(buttons[5],gbc);

        buttons[6] = new JButton("7");
        buttons[6].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,60));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        buttons[6].addActionListener( buttonHandler);

        add(buttons[6],gbc);

        buttons[7] = new JButton("8");
        buttons[7].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,60));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        buttons[7].addActionListener( buttonHandler);

        add(buttons[7],gbc);

        buttons[8] = new JButton("9");
        buttons[8].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,60));
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        buttons[8].addActionListener( buttonHandler);

        add(buttons[8],gbc);

        buttons[9] = new JButton("0");
        buttons[9].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,60));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        buttons[9].addActionListener( buttonHandler);
        add(buttons[9],gbc);
    }

    private class handler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            if(e.getSource() == buttons[0]){

            }

            if(e.getSource() == buttons[1]){

            }

            if(e.getSource() == buttons[2]){

            }

            if(e.getSource() == buttons[3]){

            }

            if(e.getSource() == buttons[4]){

            }

            if(e.getSource() == buttons[5]){

            }

            if(e.getSource() == buttons[6]){

            }

            if(e.getSource() == buttons[7]){

            }

            if(e.getSource() == buttons[8]){

            }

            if(e.getSource() == buttons[9]){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `ATMKeypadPanel` `ActionListener`, you don't do anything with the button presses.  You need to save them in a `char` array that you can access from both the `ATMKeypadPanel` class and the `ATMScreenPanel` class.  An application model made up of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes should hold this `char` array.  You also need a more descriptive class name than `handler`.

Comment: Thank you mister! Man I have a lot to learn :<